Problem in updating apt
I just started using Linux(Ubuntu 24.04 LTS). To update the apps I used the following command in the terminal:
sudo apt update

and I got the following error:
E: Malformed entry 1 in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Why am I getting the error and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

you have all the info you need: file name that has the problem and the line number inside that file Use an editor and edit that file to a correct apt resource :)  We at least need line 1 from that file to answer your question so edit it in if you need more help

And please if you want to send more questions, read the Help files in the bottom of screen.
